# How to get the index number of a key in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP as the following:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [41] => 20
        [2] => 42
        [3] => 30
        [12] => 94
        [32] => -2
        [39] => -3
        [40] => -15
    )
```

I just want to fetch the index number of a particular key, like the index number of the key `41` is `0`, index number of the key: `2` is `1`, and so on. So please tell me how to do it in PHP. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick way

```
$number = array_search($index, array_keys($array));
```

Long way

```
$i = 0;
$number = false;
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
if ($key == $index){
    $number = $i;
    break;}
$i++;
}
```

Comment: @NavedAhmed did you want to make this as answered?

Comment: yupp... i wanted to make it as answered, but didn't know how to do it.

Comment: @NavedAhmed Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".If you solved the question yourself without help from an answer, post an answer yourself describing the solution, and then accept that.

Answer (score 0):

If the memory usage is out of question i would maintain a second array which would hold the key-index relations. Otherwise you have to search your array for the specified index (using a foreach cycle).

Comment: And it's a nice answer. I always forget the array_ functions. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function multiarray_keys($ar)
{
   foreach($ar as $k => $v) 
  {
    $keys[] = $k;
    if (is_array($ar[$k]))
        $keys = array_merge($keys, multiarray_keys($ar[$k]));
  }
   return $keys;
}
?>
```

Example code:

```
<?php
      $array = array("color" => array("1stcolor" => "blue", "2ndcolor" => "red", "3rdcolor" => "green"),"size"  => array("small", "medium", "large"));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r(multiarray_keys($array));
echo "</pre>";
```

?>

```
Example output:

 Array
 ( 
    [color] => Array
    (
        [1stcolor] => blue
        [2ndcolor] => red
        [3rdcolor] => green
    )
    [size] => Array
    (
        [0] => small
        [1] => medium
        [2] => large
    )
 )
 Array
(
  [0] => color
  [1] => 1stcolor
  [2] => 2ndcolor
  [3] => 3rdcolor
  [4] => size
  [5] => 0
  [6] => 1
  [7] => 2
 )
```

Comment: hey nirav, thanks for the reply and I appreciate your answer.

Comment: It's not an answer to this question